# InfoPath 2013 Publishing Error

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath

I am trying to publish a form to a SharePoint Form library. When trying to publish the form I can add the columns, but when publishing I get the following error:

"InfoPath cannot save the following form: http://url.sharepoint.com/sites/test Access Denied. Before Opening files in this     location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, brows to the web site, and select the option to login automatically."

I have successfully created a form which adds content to a list but when I try to get the form library to save it as a document it fails.

I am a site collection administrator so it will not be permissions based.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message, please perform the following the steps below:

1. Authenticate to Office 365 by ticking “Keep me signed in” on the login page.
   2, Add your SharePoint sites to trusted sites at Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet options > Security > Trusted sites > Add.

   This should work fine.let me know if it works!!!!

Comment: Did this work? I am facing similar issue, not while Publishing but while submitting the form on submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this an old post, but if you are like me, and every suggested fix has not worked for you, I thought I would share how I managed to resolve the error.

Rather than saving the form to my hard drive, and then publishing it, I saved it to a location on SharePoint, and published it from there.

It's worth a shot if none of the other fixes has worked for you.